# Django removes translation in po file, string in mark_safe

Tags: django, internationalization, django-admin

I try to translate string, which is in mark_safe() function:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as ug
...   
mark_safe('<div style="text-align:center"><a href="/calendar/" target="_blank" onclick="return open_popup(this); return false">%s</a></div>' % ug(u'show full calendar'))
```

Unfortunately, when I run run django-admin.py makemessages -l pl, it doesn't include this string in .po file. I have to edit it manually, write this line and then it works fine (the string is translated). It happens each time I run makemessages.

Answer (score 1):

Import it and use as underscore instead:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as ug
_('this is seen')
ug('this is not')
```

Comment: What if I need both ugettext and ugettext_lazy in one file?

Comment: Do not alias them in your import.  Just use from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy, ugettext.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem was with mark_safe and ug:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as ug
...   
mark_safe('<div style="text-align:center"><a href="/calendar/" target="_blank" onclick="return open_popup(this); return false">%s</a></div>' % ug(u'show full calendar'))
```

should be:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as ug
...   
mark_safe('<div style="text-align:center"><a href="/calendar/" target="_blank" onclick="return open_popup(this); return false">%s</a></div>') % ug(u'show full calendar')
```

Notice the brackets.