# Django how to mark_safe a link but not the arguments in a gettext translation

Tags: django, django-templates, gettext

Let say we have a message like this :

```
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                _('Document <a href="%(url)s">%(doc_type_name)s %(name)s (%(fname)s)</a> created.') % {
                    'doc_type_name': conditional_escape(document.doc_type.name),
                    'name': conditional_escape(document.title),
                    'fname': conditional_escape(document.name),
                    'url': document.get_absolute_url()
                })
```

Here it will work only if we display the message with `{{ message|safe }}` but we don't want that since if there is some code in `%(name)` it will be executed too.

If I use:

```
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                mark_safe(_('Document <a href="%(url)s">%(doc_type_name)s %(name)s (%(fname)s)</a> created.') % {
                    'doc_type_name': conditional_escape(document.doc_type.name),
                    'name': conditional_escape(document.title),
                    'fname': conditional_escape(document.name),
                    'url': document.get_absolute_url()
                }))
```

The `mark_safe` doesn't work.

I read a solution over there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12600388/186202

But it is the reverse that I need here:

```
_('Document %s created.') % mark_safe('')
```

And as soon as it goes through the `ugettext function` it is not safe anymore.

How should I do?

Comment: Some clues here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053258/how-do-i-output-html-in-a-message-in-the-new-django-messages-framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to mix view and logic by placing HTML inside Python code. Well, sometimes you just have to do this but it is not the case.

mark_safe() returns SafeString object which is treated by Django templates specially. If SafeString evaluated  by ugettext or % you will get string again, it is an expected behaviour. You can not mark safe only formatting string, either complete output with doc name/title etc or everything is not safe. Ie, it will not work this way.

You can put HTML into template and use render_to_string(), and probably it is the best option.

Are document title, name and doc_type.name set by user? If not, you can skip mark_safe and document using HTML in document properties as feature.

Answer (score 2):

Previous response are correct: you should avoid mixing python and html as much as possible.

To solve your issue:

```
from django.utils import six  # Python 3 compatibility
from django.utils.functional import lazy
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
mark_safe_lazy = lazy(mark_safe, six.text_type)
```

then:

```
lazy_string = mark_safe_lazy(_("<p>My <strong>string!</strong></p>"))
```

Found in django documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#s-other-uses-of-lazy-in-delayed-translations